# Not able to use Jinja template in PostgresOperator for filename of sql script

Tags: python, postgresql, bash, airflow, postgres-operator

Have been searching for this issue, but all the answers are old and not relevant to my issue.
I am trying to pass a `sql` parameter as a Jinja Template, but not able to. I am a bit new to Airflow, here is the code, I am not sure if the Jinja templating works in PostgresOperator or not. If there is any other way we can pass please let me know, again I am not trying to pass the jinja template inside the SQL query or file, I am passing the name of the SQL file using the Jinja template which it is not able to render.

PostgerOperatorCode:

```py
write_to_postgres = PostgresOperator(
        task_id ="write_to_postgres",
        postgres_conn_id="mypostgres",
        #TODO investigate, why this is not working
        sql ="queries{{ execution_date.hour }}{{ execution_date.day }}.sql"
    )
```

The templating is working on BashOperator, and PythonOpertor, but not in Postgres.
Airflow Webserver in UI says, not able to render templates.

[image: Postgres render]

BashOperatorCode:

```bash
 extract_gz = BashOperator(
        task_id="extract_downloaded_gz",
        bash_command="gunzip --force /opt/airflow/dags/wikipageviews{{ execution_date.hour }}{{ execution_date.day }}.gz"
    )
```

For BashOperator for the same code it works:
[image: BashOperator]

UPDATE:
One thing I noticed weird is when I do not put .sql in the `sql` parameter, the template gets rendered properly, which seems weird. Here is the screenshot with Jinja Template rendered without the .sql extension in `sql` parameter, but it works in bash operator as you can seen in the above code which uses .sql at end.

```py
  write_to_postgres = PostgresOperator(
        task_id ="write_to_postgres",
        postgres_conn_id="mypostgres",
        #TODO investigate, why this is not working
        sql="queries{{ execution_date.hour }}{{ execution_date.day }}"
)
```

OUTPUT of Render [image: render output successfull]

Answer (score 0):

This is one potential way we can do it, and for me, it is working.

```py
def _write_to_postgres(execution_date):
    hour = execution_date.hour
    day = execution_date.day
    filename = f"queries{hour}{day}.sql"
    import psycopg2
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database="airflow",user='airflow', password='airflow', host='postgres', port= '5432')
    except:
        raise AirflowFailException
    else:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        with open(f"/opt/airflow/dags/{filename}","r") as f:
            for statement in f.readlines():
                print(statement)
                cursor.execute(statement)
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
``
```